# How to stop unintentional UNSUBSCIRBE happening possibly via a bot or a security email scan from the customer end

Tags: asp.net, email, security, bots

The customer are complaining that they have been unsubscribed from the emails though they have not clicked on any Unsubscribe link in the emails. Upon checking user activity we find there are simultaneous clicks on all the links present in a single email. May be this is an activity of a **BOT** or **Email security scan** from customer end.  we are getting complaints from email like "someEmail@**gmail.com**", "someEmail@**hotmail.com**" and also "someEmail@**customerDomain.com**" etc.
My code is in **.NET** and on click on "**Unsubscribe**" link from the email, its triggers an api call.
How to stop/mitigate this unintentional unsubscribe ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below links, May be they will help in solving the issue.
https://help.goacoustic.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042532294-Recipient-email-server-security-causes-link-clicking

https://community.constantcontact.com/t5/Get-Help/Multiple-click-throughs-from-the-same-person/m-p/350802

Comment: those links are NOT giving a solution but are helping in giving some guidance.